# pandas udf as a window function in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

The goal is to use a [pandas user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/sql/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs) as a window function in `pyspark`.  Here is a minimal example.

`df` is a `pandas` DataFrame and a `spark` table:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
     'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.createDataFrame(df).createOrReplaceTempView('df')
```

Here is `df` as a `spark` table

```
In [10]: spark.sql('SELECT * FROM df').show()
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  2|  4|
|  2|  5|
|  3|  6|
|  3|  7|
+---+---+
```

The minimal example is to implement a cumulative sum of y partitioned by x.  Without any pandas user-defined function that looks like:

```
dx = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT x, y,
    SUM(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) AS ysum
    FROM df
    ORDER BY x""").toPandas()
```

where `dx` is then

```
In [2]: dx
Out[2]:
   x  y  ysum
0  1  1     1
1  1  2     3
2  2  3     3
3  2  4     7
4  2  5    12
5  3  6     6
6  3  7    13
```

And a non-working attempt to do the same with `pandas_udf` is

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

@pandas_udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def func(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return x.cumsum()
spark.udf.register('func', func)

dx = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT x, y,
    func(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) AS ysum
    FROM df
    ORDER BY x""").toPandas()
```

which returns this error

```
AnalysisException: Expression 'func(y#1L)' not supported within a window function.;
...
```

UPDATE
Based on answer by [wwnde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8986975/wwnde), solution was

```
def pdf_cumsum(pdf):
    pdf['ysum'] = pdf['y'].cumsum()
    return pdf
dx = sdf.groupby('x').applyInPandas(pdf_cumsum, schema='x long, y long, ysum long').toPandas()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mapInPandas` from Map Pandas Function API

```
sch =df.withColumn('ysum',lit(3)).schema
def cumsum_pdf(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for pdf in iterator:
      yield pdf.assign(ysum=pdf.groupby('x')['y'].cumsum())

df.mapInPandas(cumsum_pdf, schema=sch).show()
```

Outcome

```
+---+---+----+
|  x|  y|ysum|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  1|   1|
|  1|  2|   3|
|  2|  3|   3|
|  2|  4|   7|
|  2|  5|  12|
|  3|  6|   6|
|  3|  7|  13|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Don't think you need the ```groupby``` within the udf as at that point there will be only a single value for ```x```.

Comment: You can use mapInPandas if you do not want groupby. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  Preferred the first answer via ```applyInPandas``` just did not understand why using ```groupby``` within the user-defined function was needed.  See the edited question.